Implementing power function in two different ways. What's the big O difference between these two codes?

1:
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n < 0:
            return 1.0/self.myPow(x, -n)
        elif n==0:
            return 1
        elif n == 1:
            return x
        elif n%2 == 1:
            return self.myPow(x, n//2) * self.myPow(x, n//2) * x
        else:
            return self.myPow(x, n//2) * self.myPow(x, n//2)


2:
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n==0:
            return 1
        elif n==1:
            return x
        elif n < 0:
            return 1 / self.myPow(x, -n)
        elif n%2 == 1:
            return x * self.myPow(x, n-1)
        else:
            return self.myPow(x*x, n//2)



I implemented power functions in two different ways.
I was expecting the time complexity to be the same, but when trying on leetcode, 1) timed out and failed for some examples, but 2) succeeded.
Is there a reason why that was the case? I thought time complexity would be the same for both.

A side note: big-O time complexity (which deals with asymptotic behavior of the time function), and actual running time are 2 different things.

Why would you call a Recursive function twice, with the same parameters? self.myPow(x, n//2) * self.myPow(x, n//2) That's going to lead to potentially exponentially higher number of total calls...

The order of if conditions should not affect the complexity in this particular case and has negligible effect on performance. The biggest difference is that there are 2 recursive calls of self.myPow(x, n//2) in both last cases of Solution #1. You should have instead called it once, stored it in a variable, and multiplied them together to avoid redundancy.
# 1
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n < 0:
            return 1.0/self.myPow(x, -n)
        elif n==0:
            return 1
        elif n == 1:
            return x
        elif n%2 == 1:
            half_pow = self.myPow(x, n//2)
            return half_pow * half_pow * x
        else:
            half_pow = self.myPow(x, n//2)
            return half_pow * half_pow

This reduces the complexity from O(n) to O(log(n)), the same as that of Solution #2

If you watch closely those two implementation are of two different complexities, the first one has a time complexity of O(2^log n) = O(n) and the second one has a complexity of O(log n).
For the first implementation we can say that each time, on average, two calls are made to myPow while in the second one the recursive function is called at most one time for execution. Even if in the first implementation you try to subdivide the problem to n//2 it become futile when you call the function two times to have the same result.
N.B. if you store the value of self.myPow(x, n//2) in a variable you avoid those redundant calls to the function, making it become of complexity O(log n).
Here it is an analysis on the code, line by line:
1:
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n < 0: # O(1)
            return 1.0/self.myPow(x, -n) # O(log n)
        elif n == 0: # O(1)
            return 1 # O(1)
        elif n == 1: # O(1)
            return x # O(1)
        elif n % 2 == 1: # O(1)
            # O(2 * log n + 1) = O(log n) - Two recursive calls on n//2 and a multiplication (see my explanation before)
            return self.myPow(x, n//2) * self.myPow(x, n//2) * x
        else: # O(1)
            # O(2 * log n) = O(log n) - Two recursive calls with n//2 (see my explanation before)
            return self.myPow(x, n//2) * self.myPow(x, n//2)

2:
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n==0: # O(1)
            return 1 # O(1)
        elif n==1: # O(1)
            return x # O(1)
        elif n < 0: # O(1)
            # O(log n) since it will have the same complexity of a call with n positive, that is the same complexity of the greater between the two following returns
            return 1 / self.myPow(x, -n)
        elif n%2 == 1: # O(1)
            # O(log n) since it will resolve with n as even, so it will follow the "n-even complexity"
            return x * self.myPow(x, n-1)
        else: # O(1)
            # O(log n) since it actively reduces the problem by its half
            return self.myPow(x*x, n//2)

